# Regex with posix regex.h faild to match

Tags: c++, regex, qnx

I used the regex.h library on a qnx6.6 system.

Unfortunately, the compiler does not provide the C++  library and I have a problem with regex.h which I cannot explain.

Maybe someone can tell me why my regex does not match.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
  regex_t parse_regex_;
  std::string match_pattern_ = "^\\d*[1-9]\\d*";
  auto return_errno = regcomp(&parse_regex_, match_pattern_.c_str(),
                              (REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB));

  std::string test_string = "000187149889";
  auto regex_pass = regexec(&parse_regex_, test_string.c_str(), 0, nullptr, 0);

  if (regex_pass != 0) {
    char error_c_str_buffer[100];
    regerror(regex_pass, &parse_regex_, error_c_str_buffer,
             sizeof(error_c_str_buffer));
    std::cerr << "regexec() :" << regex_pass
              << " regerror() :" << error_c_str_buffer << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output: *regexec() :1 regerror() :regexec() failed to match*

My regex should recognize if the content of the test_string is only digits from 0 - 9 and at least one digit is 1-9.

Comment: The code shown doesn't compile -- please provide a [mcve].  You might also try replacing `\\d` with `[0-9]` in case the regex library doesn't support `\d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d` is not supported by `<regex.h>`, use `[0-9]` instead

```
std::string match_pattern_ = "^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$";
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/abdW8KEcY)

Comment: Thank you a lot Jarod42 :) is there a documentation about which functionallites are supported by regex.h, i dindt find one.

Comment: I have looked at https://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec which points to https://linux.die.net/man/7/regex